# How to delete range of controls in flowLayoutPanel c#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I have `flowLayoutPanel` and I added 6 `buttons` statically to it and then at the run-time I add some more `buttons`.

Now without clicking on any `button` (buttons in flowLayoutPanel) I want to remove a range of `buttons` (the ones which were created at run-time) based on their location / index.
For example: I already added 6 `buttons` statically and then at run-time I added 10 more `buttons` (16 buttons in total), now for example I want to remove `buttons` between the 8th and 12th. I think there might be an `index` for each control in the `flowLayoutPanel` and if I know the index of the `buttons` that would be helpful.

```
private void RemoveSomeButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Remove buttons between the 8th and 12th
}
```

Anyone knows how to do that?
Thank you

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @ TaW . Windows Forms as I said.

Comment: __Tag__ it then!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index these controls yourself, create a list to store your statically added buttons:

```
static List<Button> myButtonsList;

void InitializeButtons() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        Button b = new Button();
        flowLayout.Controls.Add(b);
        myButtonsList.Add(b);
    }
}
```

And then add each button created at runtime to that list, now you have an index, assigned to each button

```
void CreateButtonAtRuntime() {
    Button b = new Button();
    flowLayout.Controls.Add(b);
    myButtonsList.Add(b);
}

void DeleteButtons(int fromInd, int toInd) {
    for (int i = toInd; i >= fromInd; i--) {
        Button b = myButtonsList[i];
        flowLayout.Controls.Remove(b);
        myButtonsList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove controls based on their index

```
private void RemoveControls(FlowLayoutPanel panel, int first, int last)
{
    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++)
        panel.Controls.RemoveAt(first);
}
```

Comment: What if there is other controls in the panel? Also your method will delete say 4th control, all the controls after 4th will shift back one, then your method deletes 5th control (which was 6th before), and the original 5th control remains, also this might cause `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Well, he said that he wants to delete controls by their index. So he knows what controls are in the panel.  And I delete first element ever (in your example the 4th N times)

Comment: oh, didn't notice, sorry